# How to give incremented numbers when printing data in file?

Tags: c, increment

In this code, I am having a problem but don't know how to solve it. I need to print the result in file with incremented numbers. I used `line++` but it'll only work in the loop and I want that if someone printed something then printing again should require the line number to increment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "a");
  char string[STRING_LEN];
  int line = 1;

  printf("Enter the string: ");
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

  fprintf(fp1, "%d,%s\n", line++, string);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not exactly clear what do you want to do. Do you want that the next time someone enters a new line the line number should be previous line number + 1. I think with current code it might be coming 1 always ?

Comment: fgets() stores the read newline into the buffer. So, you don't need to add an extra '\n' in the last fprintf().

Comment: @DeepakPatankar you're right. I want to enter 1 plus if someone enters the data again.

Comment: For the same you will need the line number of the last line in your file and then you can change `int line = 1` to that line number. One way to get this line number is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-count-number-lines-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  char string[STRING_LEN];
  int line;
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "a+r");

  fscanf(fp1, "%d,%s\n", &line, string);
  printf("Enter the string: ");
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
  fprintf(fp1, "%d,%s", ++line, string);
  
  fclose(fp1);
  return 0;
}
```

First, we read line from file, parse it and get `line` value, then write back incremented value. And do not forget to close file.